# Firebase Authentication using a custom domain - Blank page after selecting my google account

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

I'm using Firebase Authentication for my web app, and customizing the redirect domain for Firebase Authentication's Google Sign-In feature so that Google's authentication page will show `Continue to: mydomain.io`,

I followed [Firebase's documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#expandable-4):

1. Domain Hosting

[Firebase Hosting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDUC7.png)

[Cloudflare config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fKIU.png)

2. Add `auth.mydomain.io` to the list of authorized domains in the Firebase console

[Firebase console authorized domains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kStn6.png)

3. In the Google OAuth setup page, whitelist the URL of the redirect page which is `https://auth.mydomain.io/__/auth/handler`

[Google OAuth client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUId4.png)

4. Edit my app's JavaScript code:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
 ...
 authDomain: "auth.mydomain.io",
 ...
}
```

Running my app locally, I can see my domain is properly linked to my app.

[Login: Continue to mydomain.io](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icXGH.png)

But, when I select a Google account to connect to, nothing happens. In the popup, I am redirected to `auth.mydomain.io` with a blank page & an infinite loading bar at the top

EDIT: I also have the same problem using Facebook OAuth

[After selecting the account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YGnG.png)

After maybe 10 seconds the popup closes by itself and I get the following error in my local app console:

```
FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/popup-closed-by-user).
    at createErrorInternal (assert.ts:122:1)
    at _createError (assert.ts:83:1)
    at popup.ts:283:1
```

When I change the app's JavaScript configuration to `myapp.firebaseapp.com` for the `authDomain` property, it works fine and I can login with my google account

```
const firebaseConfig = {
 ...
 authDomain: "myApp.firebaseapp.com",
 ...
}
```

Comment: Open browser DevTools on the popup and look for errors.

Comment: I already did that but there is absolutely no log in the console. I put a breakpoint before closing the popup but no error is showing up in the console unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coming back with some good news. **It now works perfectly**, though I haven't changed anything.
Give it 24h-48h if you are in the same situation I was.

Comment: I'm thinking it didn't work until the SSL cert for your custom domain was operative.  I see when it instructs on setting up the A record it notes "Your site will show a security certificate warning for a few hours, until the certificate has been provisioned."  Thanks for the guide!

Comment: Hey, one question... Did you need to upload some script to your auth.mydomain.io? Or do you need to configure the domain and it works magically?